# Select 5 random rows based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I want to get 5 random cases per Agent from a RawData where [Reviewer] = 'G'. If an agent does not have 5 cases that match this criteria then take the required number of random cases where [Reviewer] = 'P'

- John has 5 cases where [Reviewer] = 'G' so these 5 cases should appear in the results
- Dan has 2 cases where [Reviewer] = 'G' so 3 random cases where [Reviewer] = 'P' should be included in results
- Pat has 6 cases where [Reviewer] = 'P' so 5 random cases should be in the results
- Mary has 2 cases where [Reviewer] = 'G' so 3 random cases where [Reviewer] = 'P' should be included in results
- Joe has 1 case where [Reviewer] = 'G' and only 2 cases where [Reviewer] = 'P' so all three cases should be included in results

Raw Data & Example of desired results:

[image: Raw Data & Example of desired results]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially  [Ask]. Also, sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: You have just a single table that violates 2nd normal form, nothing else? Some actual / simplified DDL would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You want to rank an agent's records first by reviewer, then randomly. Use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
select [Date], agent, [Case], accuracy, reviewer
from
(
  select
    [Date], agent, [Case], accuracy, reviewer,
    row_number() over (partition by agent order by reviewer, checksum(newid())) as rn
  from mytable
) ranked
where rn <= 5
order by agent, reviewer;
```